# Unable to customize HyperLink Manager in Rich Text Editor in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I am trying to customize the HyperLink Manager in Rich Text Editor to add some extra fields.

**Sitecore version: 9.2**

I followed these two articles:

**https://www.awareweb.com/blog/customizing-sitecores-rich-text-editor-dialogs**

**https://www.awareweb.com/blog/customizing-sitecores-hyperlink-manager-to-track-onclick-events**

I added LinkManager.ascx to the solution (following the sitecore shell folder hierarchy). Then, I added the new fields that I wanted to add. After that, I deployed the LinkManager.ascx to the local website. I don't see the newly added field in the Hyperlink Manager dialog box.

[image]

Please let me know if I am missing something. Any help, suggestions or insights with be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I am posting answer hoping it may help someone in future.
So when I deployed LinkManager.ascx to the local site in this folder **\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Dialogs**, I still hadn't 
pointed to this LinkManager to be used, thus sitecore was still using Telerik.Web.UI's Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.DialogControls.LinkManager.ascx (found in Telerik.Web.UI>Resources)

Now, in **\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx**, I pointed to the desired LinkManager's path. i.e **ExternalDialogsPath="~/sitecore/shell/controls/rich text editor/Dialogs/"**
[image]